# Clear status doesn't work with status=None

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am writing a short command that will let me set my status to anything I want but I read the documentation and there is no way to clear the status. The only thing I found was a discussion from 3 years ago which does not work

Here is my attempt:

```
@bot.command()
    async def statc(c):
        print(f"Works")
        await bot.change_presence(status=None)
```

Comment: out of curiosity, `change_presence(status=None)`?

Comment: no that does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.change_presence), you can set `status=None`, to quote the docs "If [status] `None`, then [Status.online](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Status.online) is used." which is the default (/clear) state.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.command()
async def stati(ctx):
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle)

@bot.command()
async def statc(c):
    await bot.change_presence(status=None)

bot.run('app token')
```

Comment: sorry this does not work, the bot, however, clears the status when it goes offline

Comment: @DanA Are you even sure this command gets exxecuted? add a `print()` or something to the `def statc`.

Comment: very weird the command is not even being executed you are right

Comment: @DanA I figure it has to do with your setup in general, perhaps work out if your `command_prefix` is correct and that the bot actually works, or that you don't have another `statc` command. Try changing the name of the function too.

Comment: what do you mean change the function

Comment: @DanA `async def mycoolfunction(c):` instead. and send a message to the bot with `!mycoolfunction` for instance.

Comment: @DanA We can't help you unless you post all the relevant code in the question then, as we don't know what you have tried or haven't tried. You really should add all the debugging things you've tried otherwise we're just wasting time asking things you've already tried. For instance, try this [minimal example](https://gist.github.com/Torxed/7846099b51980db06d15595225c419b9), if that doesn't work I'm pretty sure you have another issue.

Comment: DING DING DING It works, apparently the bot does not work with some functions

Comment: @DanA As I've mentioned, you probably had a problem else where in your code. Don't forget to mark your questions as solved if this helped you. That's what keeps us going helping people.